# What are the risks of using eval to assign a function to a variable by name, using string input?

Tags: javascript, regex, security, eval, server-side

I need to allow user configuration of which functions in a library should be run by a server-side Javascript process. The user can enter this list of functions in a text box (whitespace-separated). When the process runs, it splits the list by whitespace, and then each function is found and run using the following statements:

var curFunction = eval(functionName);
curFunction();

Nobody can set the list of functions to run, except our internal developers, but I wanted to safeguard this anyway, since the server side script can alter our database.

My question is whether I am doing enough to safeguard our database, by rejecting any functionName param that matches one or more of the following:

1. The regular expression /[^A-Za-z0-9_]/
2. The regular expression of Javascript keywords /^\s*nlapi|^\s*nlobj|^\s*break\s*$|^\s*case\s*$|^\s*catch\s*$|^\s*continue\s*$|^\s*debugger\s*$|^\s*default\s*$|^\s*delete\s*$|^\s*do\s*$|^\s*else\s*$|^\s*finally\s*$|^\s*for\s*$|^\s*function\s*$|^\s*if\s*$|^\s*in\s*$|^\s*instanceof\s*$|^\s*new\s*$|^\s*return\s*$|^\s*switch\s*$|^\s*this\s*$|^\s*throw\s*$|^\s*try\s*$|^\s*typeof\s*$|^\s*var\s*$|^\s*void\s*$|^\s*while\s*$|^\s*with\s*$/

The idea is to restrict the input to function names, but not allow anything else like parentheses or keywords, so the user shouldn't be able to make anything work except just the function variable assignment.

Is there any way to weasel around this? The functions do not need to take differing params, so all we need is the function name.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you should be doing:

```
var functions = {
    "doSomething":function() {...},
    "somethingElse":function() {...},
    "dontMessUp":function() {...}
};
```

Once you have your valid functions defined like this, just call:

```
var functionName = "doSomething";
functions[functionName] && functions[functionName]();
```

Comment: Good answer - always whitelist, never blacklist.